# How to make border height appear same on all devices

Tags: html, css

I have designed two borders. One behind the image (black border) and the second on the image (green border). I want the height of both borders same across all the mobile devices. I have set the height of a border according to the mobile screen size of 320px, But when I try to change the screen size to a different size e.g(375px, 414px, etc), the height comes out of its normal size. How do I make it appear same on every device. I am using the mobile-first approach.

HTML:

```
<div class="img-border1" >
            
     <img src="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/201209140756-jimenez-covid-19-vaccine-distribution-rural-us-dnt-vpx-super-169.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.img-border1{
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid #000;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
  
    img{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        transition: .25s;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;  
    }
    
    &::after{
        border: 4px solid green;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 15px;
        right: -20px;
        bottom: -15px;
    }
}
```

Here is the visual representation: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zaidik/pen/dypWJJb)

You can check by setting the different mobile screen sizes in the chrome dev tool.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a library like Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes I am very sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the height of your `div`. But the inconsistant height of your image. Because your are using % as its width, so height also becomes smaller.

The height of your div is `constant` and always 200px;

[image]

So, you just need to fix the height and width of your image. It must always be 200px or so, if it becomes smaller, the div behind (`<div class="img-border1" >` will still have height: 200px and it will look as broken);

**Change SCSS to:**

```
.img-border1{
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid #000;
    height: 200px;
    width:350px;
    background: yellow;
  
    img{
        position: absolute;
        height: 180px;
        transition: .25s;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;  
    }
    
    &::after{
        border: 4px solid green;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 15px;
        right: -20px;
        bottom: -15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I tried giving width: 100% and height same as a border which is 200px. Now the image looks very stretchy on mobile size over 400px. Would you recommend something changing now?